# Is there a way to delay/organize page load without javascript?

Tags: lazy-loading

In the quest for fast (initial) page load, I'm wondering if there is a way to organize page load without using any javascript?

I don't know if you really need the delay capacity of javascript, if you could just order the way the content of your page loads (header-->content-->sidebars-->elements further down...

Or am I wrong about getting good page ratings without delaying?

Comment: Are you referring to "JavaScript"? Java is to JavaScript like car is to carpet.

Comment: I am--was. Sorry for the voiture-pas.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can write a page without using js at all (for example pure html like it was in the beginning of web) and if you will use css3 then your page could look modern and dynamic. But it is hard to imagine any rich and modern functionality without support of scripting on client side (like autoload data on scroll via ajax, or collecting statistics or having local storage etc). 
If you are thinking about fastest way to load initial page - try to think about caching static objects like images, js files etc, and to load static data first giving perception of a fast load,  loading dynamic data on a background using js.  However this is quite a spread topic and there are different techniques how to do such effect, i would recommend searching for topics about architectures  of modern high load web apps like facebook, youtube, twitter and so on.